# What is wrong with my @component?

Tags: java, spring

I want to autowire my components , but it seems I cannot figure it out. I know how to do it with @Autowired & @Qualifier using context:annotation-config in my xml. But how can I do the same job with components? My snippet is:

### **The component where I want to inject bean.**

```
@Component
    public class Pianist implements Performer{

       private Instruments instrument;

       @Autowired
       public void makeInstrument(Instruments instrument) {
           this.instrument = instrument;
       }

        @Override
        public void perform() {

            instrument.play();    
        }
```

### **My component which will be injected:**

```
    @Component
    public class Piano implements Instruments{

        @Override
        public void play() {
            System.out.println("Piano");
        }  
    }
```

### **My xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package = "com.city.lt">
    </context:component-scan>  

</beans>
```

### **My main:**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("builder.xml");
    Performer performer = (Performer)context.getBean("Pianist");
    performer.perform();
```

### **Then I try to run it, I am getting this error:**

```
Could not autowire method: public void com.city.lt.Pianist.makeInstrument(com.city.lt.Instruments);
```

What is wrong with that? Thanks

EDITED: stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pianist': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.city.lt.Pianist.makeInstrument(com.city.lt.Instruments); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.city.lt.Instruments] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [guitar, piano]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.city.lt.main.main(main.java:11)
```

Comment: could you provide some more lines of the stackstrace?

Comment: is `Piano` in the same package? i.e. under `com.city.lt`? If it is not, then you have to provide the package of `Piano` in component scan

Comment: yes, it is in the same package. Ok i will edit it with more info about my error;

Comment: could you post the Guitar class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the `@Autowired` on a setter/constructor/or field.
If you chose setter, please name it like a setter

```
   @Autowired
   public void setInstrument(Instruments instrument) {
       this.instrument = instrument;
   }
```

All Beans created start with a lower case (by default):

```
Performer performer = (Performer)context.getBean("pianist");
```

The problem is that you have 2 implementations of Instrument. Spring does not know which one to chose (because it is really uncreative and doesn't care about music)

You need to tell Spring what exactly it should use. Ether by annotating one with @Primary or wire all implementations into a Collection or use the implementation class you want to wire as field type or use `@Qualifier("piano")` with your autowired annotation.

```
   @Autowired
   public void makeInstrument(@Qualifier("piano") Instruments instrument) {
       this.instrument = instrument;
   }
```

Comment: Autowired does not matter what kind of name do you make of method. If I use <property> or smth I need to use constraint name with 'set'word.

Comment: i didn't say it matters... it's just convention

Comment: Ok, it does not matter at this time. It was named with a purpose. I changed my bean with lower case, but the same result...

Comment: But how can it be, because I have only one instrument implementation - Piano.

Comment: And If I will have 2 implementations of instrument, it cannot be wrong. Because then I sign my class with @ Component annotation I say that the bean of this class should be created automatically. If I have 2 implementations, and I sign only 1 implementation of my instrument with @ Component, it says, that "I create only that bean which class was signed with @ Component", for this reason another implementation of instrument should be ignored, because it would not be signed with @ Component. So because of this, I do not need to narrow beans with qualifier

Comment: you obviously have another implementation named guitar... you can read it from the stacktrace.

Comment: So ok, what is the purpose of @ Component annotation then? Does it create beans automatically where this annotation appears?

Comment: how can you be sure? the the Guitar class annotated? If yes: with what

Comment: My guitar is not annotated, but my piano is annotated with @ Component. So why guitar bean was created? It was not marked with @ Component, so it cannot be created.

Comment: maybe you create an instance of guitar on your own... did you annotate instruments?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the "makeInstrument" method after, it's easier this way:

```
@Component
public class Pianist implements Performer{

   @Autowired
   private Instruments instrument;

    @Override
    public void perform() {

        instrument.play();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the stack trace

```
No unique bean of type [com.city.lt.Instruments] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [guitar, piano]
```

You have 2 classes implementing the `Instruments` interface. Spring, by default, when using `@Autowired` does this by type. As there are 2 beans of the same type it doesn't know which one to inject. (Which is also what your stack trace tells you).

To only way to make this work is to use, indeed, a `@Qualifier` to specify which one to inject.

Comment: Yes, I understand, But If I marked my only 1 implementation of instrument with @ Component, I suppose it means that "I will create this class's bean in xml", and another implementation won't be marked with that. So I will have only 1 implementation of instrument bean, right? So Why through runtime it says that I have 2 beans if I created only 1 (which was marked with @ Component)? Or I missed something?

Comment: There are 2 instances, a guitar and a piano, that is what the error tells you. That bean is somewhere either in your xml or it is also annotated with one of the supported annotations.